# Add custom prompts to Llama 2 for RAG

Tags: python, nlp, prompt, langchain, large-language-model

I have downloaded Llama 2 locally and it works. Now I want to adjust my prompts/change the default prompt to force Llama 2 to anwser in a different language like German. Here is my code:

```
from langchain.llms import LlamaCpp
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain.callbacks.manager import CallbackManager
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
# embeddings are numerical representations of the question and answer text
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings

# use a common text splitter to split text into chunks
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter

# for token-wise streaming so you'll see the answer gets generated token by token when Llama is answering your question
callback_manager = CallbackManager([StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()])

llm = LlamaCpp(
    model_path="MYPATH/llama.cpp/models/7B/ggml-model-q4_0.bin",
    temperature=0.0,
    top_p=1,
    n_ctx=6000,
    callback_manager=callback_manager, 
    verbose=True
)

# Load Pdf-File
loader = PyPDFLoader("myfile.pdf")
documents = loader.load()

# split the loaded documents into chunks 
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=20)
all_splits = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

# create the vector db to store all the split chunks as embeddings
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings()
vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(
    documents=all_splits,
    embedding=embeddings,
)

# use another LangChain's chain, RetrievalQA, to associate Llama with the loaded documents stored in the vector db
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA

qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm,
    retriever=vectordb.as_retriever()
)

question = "What is the biggest city in Germany?"
result = qa_chain({"query": question})
```

At which part do I have to insert my own prompt? As I understood correctl, now the default Llama 2 prompt is being used.  I tried to insert a prompt at the following part, but the model kept answering in English language:

```
qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm(prompt="Please answer only in the German language!"),
    retriever=vectordb.as_retriever()
)
```

I saw that the prompt template for Llama 2 looks as follows:

```
<s>[INST] <<SYS>>
You are a helpful, respectful and honest assistant. Always answer as helpfully as possible, while being safe.  Your answers should not include any harmful, unethical, racist, sexist, toxic, dangerous, or illegal content. Please ensure that your responses are socially unbiased and positive in nature.

If a question does not make any sense, or is not factually coherent, explain why instead of answering something not correct. If you don't know the answer to a question, please don't share false information.
<</SYS>>

There's a llama in my garden  What should I do? [/INST]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with a 70b fine-tuned version of llama2 which was fine-tuned with English data. To get the model answer in a desired language, we figured out, that it's best to prompt in that language. This code should also help you to see, where you can put in your custom prompt template:

```
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate

template = """Verwenden die folgenden Kontextinformationen, um die Frage am Ende zu beantworten. Wenn du die Antwort nicht kennst, sag einfach, dass du es nicht weisst. versuche nicht eine Antwort zu erfinden. Verwende maximal drei Sätze und halte die Antwort so kurz wie möglich.

Kontext:
{context}
Frage: {question}
Hilfreiche Antwort:"""

QA_CHAIN_PROMPT = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["context", "question"], template=template)

# use another LangChain's chain, RetrievalQA, to associate Llama with the loaded documents stored in the vector db
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA

qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm,
                                chain_type='stuff',
                                retriever=vectordb.as_retriever(),
                                chain_type_kwargs={"prompt": QA_CHAIN_PROMPT})

question = "Welches ist die grösste Stadt in Deutschland?"
print(qa_chain.run(query))
```

I've took some of the code from here and adapted it to your code:
[How does PromptTemplate interact with RetrievalQA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76947597/how-does-prompttemplate-interact-with-retrievalqa)

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks! Did you also experience that Llama often switches to English, even if the instruction is to answer in German?

Comment: Maybe it depends on the model and also the size. I'm using this one here: https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/Genz-70b-AWQ
I had the problem a few time with Llama2-70b-AWQ but not with this one.